# How to rotate screen on wayland

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, wayland

I want to rotate my screen on Ubuntu 20.04 (Wayland) but xrandr doesn't work. Is there an alternative of xrandr or can I make xrandr work on wayland?

Comment: Have your tried it from settings displays??

Comment: Do you mean the Resolution setting under the Displays tab? If so, Yes I did. The resolution changed but not the rotation.

Comment: I mean Orientation https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YlH6.png

Comment: Thanks, it did. I'm sorry, I didn't noticed before as I always used xrandr to rotate screen. Also, Can you please tell me a command to do the same as I need to make a shortcut for this.

Comment: I think xrandr wont work on wayland.. there is a command I tried long time ago but that does not fit for your need it seems.. Infact it is not a shortcut but command line way which needs manual interaction.. I will try to provide you that command in some time as I have to trace it from now..

Comment: Hi can you provide the out put of this command? `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig --method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111749/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-pratap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use gnome-randr. It "tries to reimplement some of the functionality of 'xrandr' for the gnome desktop using mutter's dbus-api. It currently has not been tested with fractional scaling support."

You can download it here : https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr
Then you :

```
$ chmod +x gnome-randr.py
```

You can also replace the first line by this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and run it

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py
```

It will give you current configuration and names of your monitors, like DP-1 DVI-1 HDMI-1.

Then you can use xrandr syntax :

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py --output DP-1 --rotate left
```

Help is also available for all possibilities :

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py -h
usage: gnome-randr.py [options]
    where options are:
    --current
    --dry-run
    --persistent
    --global-scale <global-scale>
    --output <output>
        --auto
        --mode <mode>
        --rate <rate>
        --scale <scale>
        --off
        --right-of <output>
        --left-of <output>
        --above <output>
        --below <output>
        --same-as <output>
        --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
        --primary
```

Comment: On a very fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, I get

    $ ./gnome-randr.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./gnome-randr.py", line 837, in <module>
     config_info = ConfigInfo(serial, monitors, logical_monitors, properties)
   ...
      File "./gnome-randr.py", line 482, in __init_output_config
        w, h, r = mode_id_to_vals(md[0])
      File "./gnome-randr.py", line 154, in mode_id_to_vals
        return (int(w), int(h), float(rate))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1080i'

Any theories? (Sorry for the terrible formatting.)

Comment: Yes it is a known issue about interlaced resolutions. ( I see you use '1080i'). I opened a bug report and submitted a fix : https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr/-/issues/2 But the original author seems unreachable to approve it. Anyway, you can still download the fixed gnome-randr.py from my repository : https://gitlab.com/sar0umane/gnome-randr/-/blob/master/gnome-randr.py

Comment: Thank you so very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

When in KDE, you can use kscreen-doctor from [libkscreen](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/libkscreen)

as example:

```
kscreen-doctor output.1.rotation.left
kscreen-doctor output.1.rotation.normal
```