# Touchscreen rotation broken in 21.04

Tags: display, touchscreen, wayland

I usually rotate my touch screen like:

```
xinput set-prop "ILITEK ILITEK-TP" 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

This does not work in 21.04, maybe because of Wayland? However I have a 2-in-1 laptop with 21.04 and the touch coordinates automatically rotate when I rotate the device so there must because some command to do this.

Naturally you would think this would go into **Settings** but I did not see anything about touch orientation.

How can I manually set the touch screen orientation?

Comment: [This answer might give you what you're looking for](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304659/1222991).

Comment: Saw that already, it is to rotate the display not touch coordinates. And besides, there should be a command to do this without having to run/maintain a script. I have a laptop with touchscreen and it auto-rotates the display AND touch coordinates when I physically rotate the device this means the sensor is telling the operating system (21.04) to rotate both display and touch....why is there not a simple command/menu option for this? Hard to believe they would miss something so obvious.